# tinyMCE always changes URL after edit configurable article and save

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

If I edit a configurable product and save then it loads and if load finisihed then URL changes from:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/login/catalog_product/edit/id/4
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/login/catalog_product/edit/id/4/back/edit/tab/product_info_tabs_customer_options/key/70b9f407554ea83f8daecaf99f6b9b6d/
```

and the images in the tinyMCE Editor are not loading anymore because the path is changed from e.g. `/media/xy/example.jpg` to `../../../../../media/xy/example.jpg` and there are many requests made because the image can't get loaded.

Why is the URL changed and why does tinyMCE Editor change the URL?

**UPDATE**

I found the bug which leaded to the unecessary requests:

```
var tinyMCEival = setInterval(function(){
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
}, 500);
```

It stopped doing the requests when I removed this code. Everything is still working, so It is not even necessary.